# Objective-C string comparison

Tags: objective-c

I have an array of names but can't seem to make the comparison work. Do I have an improper use of the language here?

```
NSLog(@"%@",[arrayOfNames objectAtIndex:0]);

if ([arrayOfNames objectAtIndex:0] == "Blue"){ 
  NSLog(@"it's Blue");
}
else {
  NSLog(@"it's not Blue");
}
```

The output is the following one:

> Blue
>
> it's not Blue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the following:

```
if ([[arrayOfNames objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"Blue"])
```

You're comparing two objects (one of the id-type, the other is a C-string) with the == operator. The comparison will fail, since they are 2 different objects. With the isEqualToString you are comparing the value of the object to the string `@"Blue"`.

Comment: Thanks, xCoder, for that world record response. Less than a minute. I appreciate your help. (I was editing my question and found you'd already answered it. Thanks again.

Comment: To expand on the answer, you're comparing two objects with the == whereas with the isEqualToString you're sending a message to compare the contents of the two objects. +1

Comment: Not even two objects; `"Blue"` is a C string, not an Objective-C object.